# Move branch and branch-specific commit history to new repository

Tags: git, github

I've got a [repo](https://github.com/hassankhan/Zepto/tree/develop) which I forked. I've since made a fair few changes in a new 'develop' branch, and would like to squash the commits from before my fork, and preserve only the commit history on my fork.

I know `git rebase -i` is supposed to do this, but not sure entirely how.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want that? What would you gain?

Comment: Apparently its disrespectful to fork a project and then completely change it, its better to create a fresh repo (I read it somewhere, can't remember where)

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- clone your repo
- checkout the right SHA1 '`S`' (just before your own modification)
- remove the .git folder
- `git init, git add, git commit`: new repo with only one commit representing the state of your repo before your modifications.
- add your original repo as a remote

Then you can [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your own modifications on top of that one commit:

```
git cherry-pick S origin/master
```

That would take:

```
x--x--x--y--y--y (origin/master)
     (S)

z--z--z          (master)
```

And would produce:

```
x--x--x--y--y--y      (origin/master)
     (S)

z--z--z--y'--y'--y'   (master)
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried cherry-picking all the commits from that point, but it fails on branch merge commits. Is the ``git rebase`` command any good for me?

Comment: @HassanKhan you can try a rebase indeed: `git rebase --onto master S origin/master`. If it still fails on merge commits, try with a `-p`: `git rebase -p --onto master S origin/master`

Comment: I did try that too, keep hitting merge conflicts and not entirely sure how to merge them in since some of the conflicted files get removed from the repo completely in later commits. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: @HassanKhan you still need to resolve the conflicts, but at least activate [`git rerere`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere), in order to memorize the resolution.

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit tired of trying to fight Git to do this, I did think this would be easier. Just gonna do a fresh commit without the history, really isn't worth all this trouble. Thanks, anyway.